# Equivalent to SRFI 42's :while in Racket's comprehensions

Tags: scheme, racket, list-comprehension

The eager comprehensions in [SRFI 42](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-42/srfi-42.html) can have a `:while` clause that runs a generator while some condition holds, for example: `(list-ec (:while (:range i 10) (< (* i i) 50)) i)` returns the list `(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` (and *stops* iteration at 7, unlike an `if`, such as in `(list-ec (:range i 10) (if (< (* i i) 50)) i)`, that would keep going but produce no more values).

In Racket, I generally prefer to use the native `for` and `for/list`, but they don't seem to have something like this built-in. What's the best way to simulate `:while` in Racket's `for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I somehow missed it in the docs: the answer is to use the [`stop-before` function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._stop-before%29%29). You can translate something like:

```
(list-ec (:while (:integers i) (< (* i i) 10))
         (:while (:integers j) (< (* (+ i 1) j) 10))
       (list i j))
```

to

```
(for*/list
     ([i (stop-before (in-naturals 0) (λ (i) (>= (* i i) 10)))]
      [j (stop-before (in-naturals 0) (λ (j) (>= (* (+ i 1) j) 10)))])
  (list i j))
```

Note that we need the starred version, `for*/list`, because `list-ec` produces nested loops by default. Also, Racket has a `#:break` clause in its comprehension, as pointed out by Asumu Takikawa, but that works differently: it doesn't limit a single generator but rather exits the whole loop.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `#:break` clause in `for` loops to do something similar. For example, here is what I think is equivalent to your example:

```
(for/list ([i (in-range 0 10)]
           #:break (> (* i i) 50))
     i)
```

This stops the iteration when the `#:break` condition holds. You can also use `#:when` to filter the iterations instead of stopping. For more options, see the [for](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28part._.Iteration_and_.Comprehension_.Forms%29) docs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's a full equivalent, what if I want to use two `:while` clauses in a single comprehension? It certainly is good for a single `:while`.

Comment: You can just `(or ...)` the negations of the two conditions.

Comment: The or trick you describe, @AsumaTakikawa, works for something like `(list-ec (:while (:while (gen1 cond1) cond2) ...)` but I meant something like `(list-ec (:while gen1 cond1) (:while gen2 cond2) ...)`. I guess in Racket I would have to nest comprehensions and use a `#:break`  in each one (plus flatten the resulting list of lists).

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to `(for/list ([x gen1] [y gen2] #:break (or (not cond1) (not cond2)) ...)`?

Comment: No, because in SRFI 42 generators give nested loops by default, that is, the `-ec` macros are like Racket's `for*` not like `for`. So `(:while g1 c1) (:while g2 c2)` runs `g1` while `c1` holds and for each value produced, starts `g2` and runs it while `c2` holds. Your `for/list` runs the generators in parallel, but not even `(for*/list g1 g2 #:break (or (not c1) (not c2)) ...)` works, since it stops the first time one of `c1` and `c2` fails, so that of `c1` holds at least once, it while do this: take the first value of `g1`  run through `g2` until `c2` fails and then will stop the whole thing!

Comment: I'm an idiot: I missed the `stop-before` function in [the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=for#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._stop-before%29%29).